# Outlook 2016 rules disappear after adding Microsoft 365 account

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

Running Office 2016 Pro on Windows 10 with latest updates. Outlook connects two accounts using POP3 without removing emails from the server. Both accounts have their data stored in the same .pst file. Have about 20 rules for mail routing and been working like this for years.

Added a new Microsoft 365 account and all the rules disappeared with the message "There are rules created with a different version of Outlook or Outlook Web Access that are not shown."

[image]

If I remove the MS 365 account, all the rules come back and everything works as before.

Does anyone know how I can have my existing POP3 accounts and add the MS 365 account without losing my rules?

Comment: [Even though the rule doesn't appear in the Rules and Alerts dialog box of the classic Outlook for Windows, the rule still runs on incoming email.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/email-management/inbox-rule-does-not-appear-in-outlook-client). At any point did you use Outlook for Windows to modify any of the rules?

Comment: @Ramhound, this turns out not to be the case. I had read that page and the rules are not running. As to Outlook for Windows, I use Outlook 2016 which works with 365. Is Outlook for Windows some other product?

Comment: In my experience if you log into a Microsoft Account with an active Office 365 subscription with Outlook 2016, Office 2016 (which includes Office 2016) will be updated, to the version included with your Office 365 subscription. `Outlook for Windows` is an updated Windows Mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before adding the M365 account, take a note of the rules of your existing POP3 accounts. Export the rules to make a backup and then remove them.
[image]

Add the M365 account into your Outlook, reconfigure the rules from scratch and see if they can be visible and work as expected. If it still doesn't work, refer to the blog below to add the "through the specified account" condition and check the result：
[Separate rules for Exchange and POP3 accounts](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/777)

Comment: This is the solution I am currently using. Was hoping MS had implemented a process for this and I simply had not found it. This will be the accepted answer if no one has a better one.

Comment: Okay, understood : )